# Plug-in 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui' contributed an invalid Menu Extension

Tags: android, eclipse

When I am trying to right click on project in Eclipse then getting this Error Log:

```
eclipse.buildId=3.6.3.201411281414-RELEASE-e43
java.version=1.7.0
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.springsource.sts.ide
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.springsource.sts.ide

Error
Wed Dec 24 19:24:17 IST 2014
Plug-in 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.menu' is invalid): org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.EnableDisableDependencyManagementActionDelegate
```

How to get rid of this?? Here am unable to push OR pull from Bit bucket (Git)..

Comment: I also get this error? Have you been able to fix it?

Comment: Same error...After months no replies? In my case I suspect this caused a lot of other problems with eclipse contextual menus...!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug in Gradle IDE Eclipse plugin. See here:
https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3979

Should be fixed in version 3.6.4 but there is no release date set yet (all information retrieved from the website above)